# Team Services How mark iteration as "completed / released " and "hide" is completed tasks?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question regarding "Work" and "Iteration".

I have created some tasks put them in "iteration 0", I set the state of the tasks to "closed".
How mark "iteration 0"  as "completed \ released" and "hide" its completed tasks?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such parameter to define iteration status. But once you finished a iteration, you can rename the iteration name as completed/released in https://account.visualstudio.com/ProjectName/_admin/_work by clicking edit for the iteration.

[image]

For task board of iteration, task (bug) workflow as New -> Active (-> Resolved) -> Closed. So the columns can’t be changed, that means closed tasks should also display in task board. But if all the tasks are closed and the parent user story also closed, then the task board will collapse that row by default. Such as the user story `pur` is closed and all it’s tasks are also closed, then this row will collapsed without showing any tasks.

[image]